# php pdo this query is not run, but it is run smoothly on phpmyadmin

Tags: php, pdo

this query smoothly run on phpmyadmin. but in my project, it is not querying.

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.est_id,p.sec_plan_number,p.plot_plan_number,
                    (select policyno from tbl_plot_statusd where est_id=p.est_id 
                    and sec_plan_number=p.sec_plan_number and plot_plan_number=p.plot_plan_number 
                    and op_id=ps.op_id) as policyno, (select nic from tbl_plot_statusd 
                    where est_id=p.est_id and sec_plan_number=p.sec_plan_number 
                    and plot_plan_number=p.plot_plan_number and op_id=ps.op_id) as nic 
                    FROM `tbl_plot` p left join tbl_plot_status ps on p.est_id=ps.est_id 
                    and p.sec_plan_number = ps.sec_plan_number and p.plot_plan_number=ps.plot_plan_number 
                    where ps.status_type_code=2 and ps.is_last_status=1 and p.isactive=1 
                    order by ps.est_id,ps.sec_plan_number,abs(ps.plot_plan_number)';
 foreach ($db->query($sql) as $d)
```

Comment: why foreach is there?

Comment: @AlivetoDie `PDOStatement` implements `Traversable` so it can be used in `foreach`

Comment: You mentioned an exception in your title. What is it?

Comment: @Phil  that i know but i think he need to run query only once and he need to  iterate records of the result. As mentioned in some-one answer

Comment: @AlivetoDie the query **is** only being executed once. OP's code is no different to `$stmt = $db->query($sql); foreach ($stmt as $d)`

Comment: @AlivetoDie this query is for table, so i need to iterate until the last record, however the code is not working, at least not given any error too.

Comment: @HarshaPriyalal  you will get error when you try to do some error reporting. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` on your current page jaust after starting`<?php` tag on top and check once

Comment: only this part of the code is give result.. but, when attach the sub query the code is not working..  $sql = "SELECT p.est_id,p.sec_plan_number,p.plot_plan_number
                        FROM `tbl_plot` p left join tbl_plot_status ps on p.est_id=ps.est_id 
                        and p.sec_plan_number = ps.sec_plan_number and p.plot_plan_number=ps.plot_plan_number 
                        where ps.status_type_code=2 and ps.is_last_status=1 and p.isactive=1 
                        order by ps.est_id,ps.sec_plan_number,abs(ps.plot_plan_number)";

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$query = $db->query($sql);
foreach ($query->fetchAll() as $d)
{

}
```

Comment: @HarshaPriyalal  what error you get when you run your code.Also can you a bit more code(full code) along with your exception you got?

Comment: can it be the problem having sub query? i do not know. every other my querying is working fine. and this also run on myadmin

Comment: $query = $db->query($sql);
               foreach ($query->fetchAll() as $d)
                {
                   print_r($d); 
                }

Comment: Are you sure it's connected to the same database your working with in phpmyadmin? What is the output of print_r($db->query(sql));?

Comment: yes it was a mistake sorry for that. but actually  nothing show when it run.

Comment: @KevinP yes, its sure working on same database. there are not any message display

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.